# Controller for Sign Up and Sign In in MVC 5 Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a project and what should i do? Should i use the same controller and model for Sign In and Sign Up or use different? Will it be easy to link them, since sign in needs to access the database linked to sign up.

Comment: If it's going to be in the same "view group" like the sign in and singup link is on the same view i would put it in same controller. If your signup logic is part of some other flow i would put it in another controller.

Comment: It's mostly only a matter of design preference, but I think you should use the same controller, but different model. Generally the adviced practice is to create separate models for separate views. This will allow more flexibility in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter, depends on how you want. I would put it in the same controller, because they are kind of same.